# Smoothdivscroll & Lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gallery, lazy-loading

I am working on a site that will house about 200+ images within the http://www.smoothdivscroll.com layout

The problem is that we need to incorporate some sort of lazyloading. The main issue I have been having is that the first images within the viewport swap src & data-original no problem. However any other items that are outside of the viewport do not swap. They still have the original transparent.gif as the source.

Here is the Lazyload file that I am using: http://pastebin.com/W05PiFLA

I have not touched the http://www.smoothdivscroll.com code at all.

Anyone know what can be done here. I am working on this for a client and timing is becoming an issue. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question.  Instead of this, though, I would probably just do an ajax call to load in more images (basically, like asynchronous paging).

Answer (score 0):

Try switch binding of the event with src change.

```
  image.bind('load', function(){
                            image.animate({opacity:1}, 1000).css({height:'auto'});
                            callback();
                    });
  image.attr("src", image.attr("data-original"));
```

Instead of this

```
    image.attr("src", image.attr("data-original")).bind('load', function(){
                            image.animate({opacity:1}, 1000).css({height:'auto'});
                            callback();
                    });
```

Comment: yes, its because sometimes the image downloads before the browser registers the event listener..And I think better is to fade the placeholder image out after the  original image is loaded..it just makes more sense.